# how to provide keyboard combination(Shift+command+F) to make google Chrome to full screen

Tags: python, selenium

Need to open the Google Chrome to Full screen while opening using Selenium Python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

Comment: don't you mean "maximize"? Like options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized") driver = ChromeDriver(options) ?

Comment: not to be maximized. need to open in full screen and im using python for selenium

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://google.com")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys('f').key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()
```

Comment: It open in Default size only.

Comment: because full-size is F11 button.. try actions.key_down(Keys.F11).key_up(Keys.F11).perform()

Comment: Will it work in MAC. in MAC F11 will show the desktop

Comment: well, sorry, guess no :) maybe actions.key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys('F').key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()  will work?

Comment: one more option is: actions.key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.COMMAND).send_keys('F').key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()

Answer (score 0):

(1) Using Actions Class : -

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(driver.findElement(locator)).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

(2)Using Robot Class

```
Robot r=new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);

r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F);
```

(3)Using Keys class

```
Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"); [Form your OWN]
```